# Win32 - Determine dirty pages for memory mapped file

Tags: windows, winapi, memory-management, memory-mapped-files

Is there a way to determine the number of dirty pages which are still awaiting to be flushed to disk for a memory mapped file/view? And if so, is it possible to determine the offsets and sizes so they can be manually flushed with `FlushViewOfFile`?

Comment: for what this need ? if want force flush data on disk - call `FlushViewOfFile` with 0 - for all view. anyway system write to disk only dirty pages

Comment: To track how much IO is outstanding and preemptively flush dirty pages to disk if there is a window where I know I wont incur page faults from reading the MMF. I have a very large number of views for some rather large files, so it isnt practical to just loop through them all and flush them all on a timer periodically.